# How can I remove Richfaces automatic panel width of 100%

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have an extendedDataTable inside of a Panel (I also tried just sticking it in a div). The width of the table extends to fill the parent instead of the parent shrinking to the content.

code for the table

```
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="../main_template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <div class="table_panel">
                <rich:extendedDataTable value="#{user_list.userList}" var="user" filterVar="filterValue" id="table"
                                        sortPriority="#{userListSortingBean.sortPriorities}"
                                        selectionMode="none"
                                        rowClasses="odd_row, even_row">
                    <rich:column sortBy="#{user.nameFirst}" filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:startsWith(user.nameFirst, filterValue)}">
                        <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.nameFirst}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column sortBy="#{user.nameLast}" filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:startsWith(user.nameLast, filterValue)}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.nameLast}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column sortBy="#{user.email}" filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:startsWith(user.email, filterValue)}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.email}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column sortBy="#{user.company.name}" filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:startsWith(user.company.name, filterValue)}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Company</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.company.name}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column sortBy="#{user.company.activeFlag}" filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:startsWith(user.company.activeFlag, filterValue)}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Company Active Status</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.company.activeFlag}" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column sortBy="#{user.company.expirationDate}" filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:startsWith(user.company.expirationDate, filterValue)}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Expiration Date</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.company.expirationDate}" />
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:extendedDataTable>
                <rich:messages />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

relevant css

```
#main_content .table_panel {

background-color: #BED6F8;
color: #0066cc;
border-width: 3px;
}

#main_content .rf-edt {
border: none;
}

#main_content .rf-edt-ftr {
border: none;
}

.even_row {
background-color: #ECF3FE;
}

.odd_row {
background-color: #FCFFFE;
}
```

and I intended to post a picture of the result, but don't have the reputation for it. What is going on Is my wrapper div is being filled by the table even though the data in the table only needs about 50% of the space. I just need the table to shrink down to it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information's sake. As of richfaces 4.3.3 this is just how the column widths work. We ended up making the table just a bit smaller than the sum of all the columns and accepting the bottom scroll bar.